# DataDog log ingestion not working on Kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, logging, devops, datadog

We followed [these instructions](https://github.com/DataDog/datadog-operator/blob/main/docs/getting_started.md) to set up DataDog in our Kubernetes 1.22 cluster, using their operator. This was installed via helm with no customisations.

The operator, cluster-agent, and per-node agent pods are all running as expected. We know that the agents are able to communicate successfully with the DataDog endpoint because our new cluster shows up in the Infrastructure List view of DataDog.

However, logs from our application's pods *aren't* appearing in DataDog and we're struggling to figure out why.

Some obvious things we made sure to confirm:

- `agent.log.enabled` is true in our agent spec (full YAML included below).
- our application pods' logs are present in `/var/log/pods/`, and contain the log lines we were expecting.
- the DataDog agent is able to see these log files.

So it seems that *something* is going wrong in between the agent and the logs being available in the DataDog UI. Does anyone have any ideas for how to debug this?

---

Configuration of our agents:

```yaml
apiVersion: datadoghq.com/v1alpha1
kind: DatadogAgent
metadata:
  name: datadog
  namespace: datadog
spec:
  agent:
    apm:
      enabled: false
    config:
      tolerations:
        - operator: Exists
    image:
      name: "gcr.io/datadoghq/agent:latest"
    log:
      enabled: true
    process:
      enabled: false
      processCollectionEnabled: false
  clusterAgent:
    config:
      admissionController:
        enabled: true
        mutateUnlabelled: true
      clusterChecksEnabled: true
      externalMetrics:
        enabled: true
    image:
      name: "gcr.io/datadoghq/cluster-agent:latest"
    replicas: 1
  clusterChecksRunner: {}
  credentials:
    apiSecret:
      keyName: api-key
      secretName: datadog-secret
    appSecret:
      keyName: app-key
      secretName: datadog-secret
  features:
    kubeStateMetricsCore:
      enabled: false
    logCollection:
      enabled: true
    orchestratorExplorer:
      enabled: false
```

Here are the environment variables for one of the DataDog agents:

```
DD_API_KEY : secretKeyRef(datadog-secret.api-key)
DD_CLUSTER_AGENT_AUTH_TOKEN : secretKeyRef(datadog.token) 
DD_CLUSTER_AGENT_ENABLED : true
DD_CLUSTER_AGENT_KUBERNETES_SERVICE_NAME : datadog-cluster-agent
DD_COLLECT_KUBERNETES_EVENTS : false
DD_DOGSTATSD_ORIGIN_DETECTION : false
DD_DOGSTATSD_SOCKET : /var/run/datadog/statsd/statsd.sock
DD_EXTRA_CONFIG_PROVIDERS : clusterchecks endpointschecks
DD_HEALTH_PORT : 5555
DD_KUBERNETES_KUBELET_HOST : fieldRef(v1:status.hostIP)
DD_LEADER_ELECTION : false
DD_LOGS_CONFIG_CONTAINER_COLLECT_ALL : false
DD_LOGS_CONFIG_K8S_CONTAINER_USE_FILE : true
DD_LOGS_ENABLED : true
DD_LOG_LEVEL : INFO
KUBERNETES : yes
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are able to see metrics, then for logs I can see two possible reason

- enable logs collection during helm installation

```
helm upgrade -i datadog --set datadog.apiKey=mykey datadog/datadog --set datadog.logs.enabled=true
```

- Wrong region configuration, by default it expects `US`.

```
helm upgrade -i datadog --set datadog.apiKey=my-key datadog/datadog --set datadog.site=us5.datadoghq.com
```

If these two are correct, make sure the pod write logs stdout/sterror

as the log path seems correct as default

```
         - name: logpodpath
            mountPath: /var/log/pods
            mountPropagation: None
```

Apart from that, you also need to white list the container list to collect log from, or you can  set the below ENV to true and it should work and collect all logs.

```
DD_LOGS_CONFIG_CONTAINER_COLLECT_ALL=true
```

Comment: Ah, I think you've inferred that I'm using helm to install the agents, but that isn't quite right – I used helm to install the **operator** (per their instructions: https://github.com/DataDog/datadog-operator/blob/main/docs/installation.md#with-helm). It's the operator which sets up the agents etc.. To your point, though, we do have log collection enabled (see the YAML file in the question), and we are in the US1 DataDog region. I've confirmed the pods output to stdout with `kubectl logs -f pod-name`.

Comment: okay i see, then i think you need to set `DD_LOGS_CONFIG_CONTAINER_COLLECT_ALL=true` as I do not see any whitelist container

Comment: Oh wow, `DD_LOGS_CONFIG_CONTAINER_COLLECT_ALL` was it! So strange… in a previous cluster – where log ingestion was working – this was set to `false`: perhaps the semantics changed / a bug was fixed between the versions of the agent we're running. Either way, thanks! If you put that suggestion in the answer I'd be happy to accept it.

Comment: Glad it help, answer updated

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/1147382/datadog-not-collecting-logs-from-file-in-kubernetes-cluster @Adiii . any help on this please.

Comment: let me take a look @Kundan